# My script isn't working correctly, but I believe that the code is right

Tags: python, chromebook

I can't figure out why my script isn't working! Can someone please help!!! I'm doing this for my CS class. Here's the code:

```
feet1 = int(input('Enter the Feet: '))
inches1 = int(input('Enter the Inches: '))
feet2 = int(input('Enter the Feet: '))
inches2 = int(input('Enter the Inches: '))

feet_sum = (feet1 + feet2)
inches_sum = (inches1 + inches2)

def check(inches_sum, feet_sum):
    while True:
        if (inches_sum) > 12:
            inches_sum -= 12
            feet_sum += 1
            return feet_sum
            return inches_sum
            break

check(inches_sum, feet_sum)

print('Feet: {} Inches: {}'.format(feet_sum, inches_sum))
```

UPDATE:
Would this work?
I'm pretty sure that it should take the variables and check to see if the inches are over 12 in a loop, and when the inches aren't over 12 it'll break the loop. Does that make sense?

```
feet1 = int(input('Enter the Feet: '))
inches1 = int(input('Enter the Inches: '))
feet2 = int(input('Enter the Feet: '))
inches2 = int(input('Enter the Inches: '))

feet_sum = (feet1 + feet2)
inches_sum = (inches1 + inches2)

def check(inches, feet):
    while True:
        if (inches_sum) > 12:
            inches_sum -= 12
            feet_sum += 1
        else:
            break

check(inches_sum, feet_sum)

print('Feet: {} Inches: {}'.format(feet_sum, inches_sum))
```

Comment: I don't see a question.  What is your definition of "working correctly" and what is the code doing instead?

Comment: I see one thing wrong right away.  You have two `return` statements at the same indention level, one right after the other.  That's never right. - What do you expect the `check` function to accomplish?  No matter how you indent it, at best I see it having no effect at all.  At worst, it never returns and your program locks up, which is what would happen now if `inches_sum < 12` (assuming the compiler would even compile it as is, which it might not).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You need to provide a [mre]. What is your code supposed to do, and what's it doing instead? What input are you giving it? You can [edit] the question. While you're there, please make the title more descriptive.

Comment: What do you suggest that I do? I'm just super lost.

Comment: Now the only two answers, mine and the new answer by @passenger are both good ones.  As he says, you may not want to bother with the function, in which case his/hers is simpler and better. Your choice.

Comment: @EthanClark, are you getting it now?  Can we answer more questions?  The way the function is returning two values IS a bit strange, and something somewhat unique to Python in its ability to do that.  You'd want to look up "tuples" and unpacking them to understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
feet1 = int(input('Enter the Feet: '))
inches1 = int(input('Enter the Inches: '))
feet2 = int(input('Enter the Feet: '))
inches2 = int(input('Enter the Inches: '))

feet_sum = (feet1 + feet2)
inches_sum = (inches1 + inches2)

def check(inches_sum, feet_sum):
    while (inches_sum) >= 12:
        inches_sum -= 12
        feet_sum += 1
    return inches_sum, feet_sum

inches_sum, feet_sum = check(inches_sum, feet_sum)

print('Feet: {} Inches: {}'.format(feet_sum, inches_sum))
```

Result:

```
Enter the Feet: 1
Enter the Inches: 26
Enter the Feet: 1
Enter the Inches: 26
Feet: 6 Inches: 4
```

Comment: What was I doing wrong? I was passing the variables through the function like you are but in a different way!

Comment: In Python, function parameters are "pass by value".  The original values outside the function are not affected.  So after the function exits, the original values in `feet_sum` and `inches_sum` haven't changed.  So you were passing them in fine, but they weren't coming back out.  What I put in front of the function call updates the values of those two variables to reflect what happened in the function.

Comment: I've got another question! 
I have to make a script that takes a float input and outputs the decimal portion of the float. Where would I even begin?
This is all I have so far: 
`x = float(input('Enter a number: '))
`

Comment: Do you have to do it numerically?  If not, you could turn it into a string and use string slicing by finding the '.' and taking one side or the other.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I have to do it numerically but I think that string slicing could work as well.

Comment: Give me a sample input and result - what do you want for 123.4567?

Answer (score 2):

Would do it without a function, otherwise you need to handle the returned values. also use while instead of if to make it more robust:

```
feet1 = int(input('Enter the Feet: '))
inches1 = int(input('Enter the Inches: '))
feet2 = int(input('Enter the Feet: '))
inches2 = int(input('Enter the Inches: '))

feet_sum = (feet1 + feet2)
inches_sum = (inches1 + inches2)

while (inches_sum) > 12:
  inches_sum -= 12
  feet_sum += 1

print('Feet: {} Inches: {}'.format(feet_sum, inches_sum))
```

Also, negative numbers are not handled, leaving that as an excercise for you :)

After everything works, you can try to extract it as a function as in Steve's answer.

Comment: Your a genius! It worked! Thank you so much, you have no Idea how confused I was XD. And should I try to keep the loops and functions simple to make them more easily understandable?

Comment: I also have another question!